# how to display image file in webdav which needs authentication in jsp?

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp, webdav

I want to display image which is in webdav server.

I used `<img>` tag, and url is my webdav server. like this

```
 <td><img src="${f:h(Product.productImageUrl)}" height=50px width=50px></td>
```

But when client login, the image doesn't come up immediately, instead, it requires webdav server login to view image.
So is there any way to pass login session at jsp code level?

Comment: If the server requires a login before they can access the content, you will have to look for another server for this purpose. You can't store images in the same location the HTML is?

Comment: Hi! Now I'm trying another way. Is there any way to display image by inputsream which is on my controller?